# Deriving Typeable and Data for GADTs?

Tags: ghc, gadt, deriving

Using:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}                                                                                                                                                                                                          
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
```

And given the following datatype:

```
data Event a where                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    PureE  :: a                   -> Event a                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    MapE   :: (a -> b) -> Event a -> Event b                                                                                                                                                                                                 

deriving instance Typeable Event                                                                                                                                                                                                             
deriving instance Data a => Data (Event a)
```

My goal is to use the `uniplate` package which requires the `Data` instance.

Is GHC able to derive `Typeable` and `Data` automatically? Since 7.8 GHC should be able to do so and afaik at least for `Typeable` it is mandatory.

I could probably write my own `Data` instance ... but why do if GHC can just derive it for me?

Comment: What is the question here? You seem to know how to use `StandaloneDeriving`, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `deriving` does not work for non Haskell98 data types. By using `b` in `MapE` I left that territory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573669/how-can-i-derive-a-data-instance-for-a-gadt-in-haskell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531420/how-can-i-get-ghc-to-generate-instances-of-data-typeable-for-gadts-with-typeable

Comment: Yep ... found those before, but as one even states: "I found a rather unclean way to work around the problem" :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with GHC 8.10.7:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data Event a where
    PureE  :: a                   -> Event a
    MapE   :: (a -> b) -> Event a -> Event b

deriving instance Typeable Event
deriving instance (forall b. Data b) => Data (Event a)
```

The trick is the quantified constraint `(forall b. Data b) => ...`, which allows GHC to instantiate `Data b` for any type `b` on-demand. It's like a "local instance declaration."